# Is there a way to access the content of logic app standard single-tenant parameters.json with powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell, azure-logic-app-standard

I'm trying to find a way to get the parameters.json of a logic app standard single-tenant using and I can't find any.

I know that the command
`Get-AzLogicApp`
exists but it works only for logic app consumption multi-tenant.

The command I found that can be used with standard is

```
$resource = Get-AzResource `
    -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroupName" `
    -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites' `
    -Name "logicAppName"
```

The returned object doesnt give any property related with parameters.json.
Is there any other way that with powershell we can access it?

Answer (score 0):

One way that you can do is to download the template file which contains parameter file too using [Export-AzResourceGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/export-azresourcegroup?view=azps-9.5.0). Below is the script that worked for me.

```
$resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "<YOUR_RESOUREGROUP_NAME>" -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites' -Name "<YOUR_LOGICAPP_NAME>"
$resource.ResourceId

Export-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName '<YOUR_RESOUREGROUP_NAME>' -Resource $resource.ResourceId -IncludeParameterDefaultValue -Force
```

However, if you want to retrieve only parameter file, you can use the below script that worked fine when reproduced from my end.

```
$resource = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName "<YOUR_RESOUREGROUP_NAME>" -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/sites' -Name "<YOUR_LOGICAPP_NAME>"
$resource.ResourceId

Export-AzResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName '<YOUR_RESOUREGROUP_NAME>' -Resource $resource.ResourceId -IncludeParameterDefaultValue -Force

$fileContent = Get-Content -Path '<PATH_TO_EXPORTED_FILE>' | ConvertFrom-Json

$schema = '"'+"`$schema"+'"'+":"+'"'+$fileContent.'$schema'+'"'
$contentVersion = '"'+"contentVersion"+'"'+":"+'"'+$fileContent.contentVersion+'"'
$parameter = $fileContent.parameters | ConvertTo-Json
$parameters = '"'+"parameters"+'"'+":"+$parameter

$parameterFile = $schema+","+$contentVersion+","+$parameters

$parameterFileJson = "{"+$parameterFile+"}" | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json 

$parameterFileJson | Out-File '<PATH>/parameters.json'
```

Results:

[image]